# Trying to convert linq Query to IQueryable

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a LINQ query from three related data tables that I need to display in a view page in MVC application.

There are one-to-many relationships between
AllFacility and Address
and AllFacility and AllPractitionerlocation.

However, when I run the application I get:

```
Unable to cast object of type
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1
[<>f__AnonymousType4`2[<>f__AnonymousType3`2
[PODSModel.Models.ODS.AllFacility,PODSModel.Models.ODS.Address]
,PODSModel.Models.ODS.AllPractitionerLocation]]' to type 
'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PODSModel.Models.ODS.AllFacility]
```

Here is the actual query from my code:

```
public IQueryable<AllFacility> getFacility(
                               int SRCFacilityID,
                               ProviderUpdateType providerUpdateType = ProviderUpdateType.FOF)
{
var facility = _ODSContext.AllFacilities
               .Where(f => f.SRCFacilityID == SRCFacilityID)
               .Join(
                    _ODSContext.Addresses,
                    oks => oks.AddressID,
                    iks => iks.AddressID,
                    (oks, iks) => new  {allfacility =  oks,  iks })
              .Join(
                    _ODSContext.AllPractitionerLocations,
                    oks1 => oks1.allfacility.AllFacilityID,
                    iks1 => iks1.AllFacilityID,
                    (oks1, iks1) => new { oks1, iks1 })
              .AsQueryable();
return (IQueryable<AllFacility>)facility;
}
```

Update: The answer that Svyatoslav Danyliv gave me fixed that error but there's more. When I modeled the code after his suggestion, I could only pick columns form the first table because that was the only model it would accept as the new parameter.

```
.Select( k => new AllFacility)
{
...
}
```

So, I created a new model that had the columns I wanted from the three joined table (.Include...). But, when I did that, EF throws an error about invalid column AllFacilityID1. I think that is because the third table has a foreign key to the first on AllFacilityID and EF renamse it for some reasn.

Any ideas on how to resolve that. I don't need that field in the final results at all (I don't think).

Thanks,

Comment: You are trying to cast `IQueryable<anonymous>` to `IQueryable<AllFacility>`. You. have to do projection via `Select(x => new AllFacility{...})`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you that worked; but, it left me with another issue. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Instead of `new { oks1, iks1 }` in Join, do `(oks1, iks1) => new AllFacility{ ... } `, here you have access to both entities and can project all needed properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a different approach here, and use the ForeignKey - InverseProperty instead of explicitly using the join. It is a great tool EF is giving you, and it's a shame not to use it in order to make life easier and the code more readable.

```
[Table("AllFacility")]
public class AllFacility 
{
    ...
   public AllFacility()
   {
      this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
      this.AllPractitionerlocations = new HashSet<AllPractitionerlocation>();
   }
        
   public long addressID { get; set; }
   public long allPractitionerlocationID{ get; set; }
                
   [InverseProperty("AllFacility")]
   public virtual Address Addresses { get; set; }
   [InverseProperty("AllFacility")]
   public virtual AllPractitionerlocation AllPractitionerlocations { get; set; }
}
        
[Table("AllPractitionerlocation")]
public class AllPractitionerlocation
{
    ...
   public long allFacilityID { get; set; }
        
   [ForeignKey("allFacilityID")]
   public virtual AllFacility AllFacility { get; set; }
}
    
[Table("Address")]
public class Address
{
    ...
   public long allFacilityID { get; set; }
        
   [ForeignKey("allFacilityID")]
   public virtual AllFacility AllFacility { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have access to the entities without the explicit join, and the joins happen under the hood. Then, you can do something like:

```
_ODSContext.Addresses 
    .Where(x => x.AllFacility.SRCFacilityID == SRCFacilityID)
    .Select(x => x.AllFacility.AllPractitionerlocations
       .Select(y => new someDto 
       {
         Property1 = x.AllFacility.someField1,
         Property2 = x.someField2,
         Property3 = y.someField3,
       })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, I'm a little confused. The one to many is AllFacility(FK:AddressID) to Address(PK:AddressID) and AllFacility(PK:AllFacilityID) to AllPractionerLocation(FK:AllFacilityID. So, AllFacility needs to be the primary table with links/joins to the other two. How would that alter your answer? Apologies but I'm just not getting this whole MVC/LinQ thing yet. I will. It just takes time. :)